# Is maven shade-plugin culprit for my jar to not work in server

Tags: java-8, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

I have developed a java application and made it a jar file. I bundled all the dependencies using `mvn clean package` maven-shaded-plugin.

My problem is that although the application works fine in my local machine, it does not work in the server environment. Whenever I run it, I get a `NullPointerException` which means the variable is not being initialized, which implies the underlying dependency is not working properly.

The original question I posted is in here: [JMS connection not connecting to remote JBoss but connects local instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274510/jms-connection-not-connecting-to-remote-jboss-but-connects-local-instance)

I tried to run this on different servers, all of which were unsuccessful. When I re-built the package again, I found these warnings, some of which say that some jars are omitted due to them being **strongly coupled**.

I am using maven-shade-plugin without another way of testing the jar on test server. Because I cannot copy entire project and re-compile at the server (an uber-jar seemed a shortcut for me to quickly test it on both Windows and Linux servers). Server machine only have java installed. It does not have maven either to re-download the dependencies there. (Also I don't want my jar to depend on maven so I can copy it and run anywhere)

Are these warnings culprit for my jar not working on the server? Please help with any other alternatives.

The complete maven log is here:

```
E:\Programs\Tutorials\Appia\appia_jms_bridge_component>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< com.gmt:component >--------------------------
[INFO] Building BRIDGE_COMPONENT 0.2.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ component ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\Programs\Tutorials\Appia\appia_jms_bridge_component\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ component ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ component ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to E:\Programs\Tutorials\Appia\appia_jms_bridge_component\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ component ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Programs\Tutorials\Appia\appia_jms_bridge_component\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ component ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ component ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ component ---
[INFO] Building jar: E:\Programs\Tutorials\Appia\appia_jms_bridge_component\target\BRIDGE_COMPONENT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) @ component ---
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.leansoft:bigqueue:jar:0.7.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.eap:wildfly-client-properties:jar:7.3.3.GA-redhat-00004 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.0.0.redhat-1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4.redhat-00002 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2.redhat-2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.48.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.activemq:artemis-commons:jar:2.9.0.redhat-00011 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client:jar:2.9.0.redhat-00011 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.activemq:artemis-hqclient-protocol:jar:2.9.0.redhat-00011 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:jar:2.9.0.redhat-00011 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.activemq:artemis-selector:jar:2.9.0.redhat-00011 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:4.1.10.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.wildfly:wildfly-naming-client:jar:1.0.13.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:jar:1.1.6.redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish:jakarta.json:jar:1.1.6.redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:5.0.18.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.7.9.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.7.9.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22.redhat-2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.wildfly.client:wildfly-client-config:jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:jar:1.5.2.Final-redhat-00002 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron:jar:1.10.8.Final-redhat-00001 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.javatech:appia:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-java:jar:0.9.10 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:2.0-M8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.8.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.8.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.8.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Skipping pom dependency org.jboss.eap:wildfly-jms-client-bom:pom:7.3.3.GA in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] BRIDGE_COMPONENT.jar, aether-api-1.7.jar, aether-impl-1.7.jar, aether-spi-1.7.jar, aether-util-1.7.jar, appia-1.0.0.jar, artemis-commons-2.9.0.redhat-00011.ja
r, artemis-core-client-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-hqclient-protocol-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-jms-client-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-selector-2.9.0.redha
t-00011.jar, asm-6.2.jar, bigqueue-0.7.0.jar, commons-beanutils-1.9.4.redhat-00002.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.redhat-2.jar, commons-io-2.5.jar, commons-lang3-3.11.j
ar, guava-25.0.0.redhat-1.jar, jakarta.json-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar, jakarta.json-api-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar, jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-
logging-3.4.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-marshalling-2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-marshalling-river-2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-remoting-5.0.18.Final-
redhat-00001.jar, jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.redhat-2.jar, jgroups-4.1.10.Final-redhat-00001.jar, log4j-1.2.17.jar, maven-aether-
provider-3.0.jar, maven-artifact-3.0.jar, maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar, maven-core-3.0.jar, maven-model-3.0.jar, maven-model-builder-3.0.jar, maven-plugin-api-3.0.ja
r, maven-repository-metadata-3.0.jar, maven-settings-3.0.jar, maven-settings-builder-3.0.jar, maven-shared-incremental-1.1.jar, maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar, netty-all-
4.1.48.Final-redhat-00001.jar, plexus-cipher-1.4.jar, plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar, plexus-compiler-api-2.8.4.jar, plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.jar, plexus-compiler-mana
ger-2.8.4.jar, plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar, plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar, plexus-java-0.9.10.jar, plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar, plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar, qdo
x-2.0-M8.jar, sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar, sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar, sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar, wildfly-client-config-
1.0.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar, wildfly-client-properties-7.3.3.GA-redhat-00004.jar, wildfly-common-1.5.2.Final-redhat-00002.jar, wildfly-elytron-1.10.8.Final-redhat-0000
1.jar, wildfly-naming-client-1.0.13.Final-redhat-00001.jar, xnio-api-3.7.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar, xnio-nio-3.7.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar define 1 overlapping resource:

[WARNING]   - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[WARNING] commons-beanutils-1.9.4.redhat-00002.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.redhat-2.jar, commons-io-2.5.jar, commons-lang3-3.11.jar, jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final-redhat
-00001.jar, jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar, wildfly-elytron-1.10.8.Final-redhat-00001.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE.txt
[WARNING] commons-beanutils-1.9.4.redhat-00002.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.redhat-2.jar, commons-io-2.5.jar, commons-lang3-3.11.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/NOTICE.txt
[WARNING] artemis-commons-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-core-client-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-hqclient-protocol-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-jms-client-2.9.0
.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-selector-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, log4j-1.2.17.jar, maven-aether-provider-3.0.jar, maven-artifact-3.0.jar, maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar, ma
ven-core-3.0.jar, maven-model-3.0.jar, maven-model-builder-3.0.jar, maven-plugin-api-3.0.jar, maven-repository-metadata-3.0.jar, maven-settings-3.0.jar, maven-settings-
builder-3.0.jar, maven-shared-incremental-1.1.jar, maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar, plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar define 2 overlapping resources:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE
[WARNING]   - META-INF/NOTICE
[WARNING] artemis-commons-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-core-client-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-jms-client-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-selector-2.9.0.redhat-0
0011.jar, commons-beanutils-1.9.4.redhat-00002.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.redhat-2.jar, jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-logging-3.4.1.Fin
al-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-marshalling-2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-marshalling-river-2.0.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jboss-remoting-5.0.18.Final-redhat-00001.jar,
 jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.redhat-2.jar, wildfly-client-config-1.0.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar, wildfly-client-properties-7.3.3.GA-
redhat-00004.jar, wildfly-common-1.5.2.Final-redhat-00002.jar, wildfly-elytron-1.10.8.Final-redhat-00001.jar, wildfly-naming-client-1.0.13.Final-redhat-00001.jar, xnio-
api-3.7.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar, xnio-nio-3.7.9.Final-redhat-00001.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/build.metadata
[WARNING] artemis-commons-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-core-client-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-hqclient-protocol-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-jms-client-2.9.0
.redhat-00011.jar, artemis-selector-2.9.0.redhat-00011.jar, maven-aether-provider-3.0.jar, maven-artifact-3.0.jar, maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar, maven-core-3.0.jar,
maven-model-3.0.jar, maven-model-builder-3.0.jar, maven-plugin-api-3.0.jar, maven-repository-metadata-3.0.jar, maven-settings-3.0.jar, maven-settings-builder-3.0.jar, m
aven-shared-incremental-1.1.jar, maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
[WARNING] jakarta.json-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar, jakarta.json-api-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar, jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar define 2 overlapping resourc
es:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE.md
[WARNING]   - META-INF/NOTICE.md
[WARNING] jakarta.json-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar, jakarta.json-api-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar define 34 overlapping classes:
[WARNING]   - javax.json.EmptyArray
[WARNING]   - javax.json.EmptyObject
[WARNING]   - javax.json.Json
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonArray
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonBuilderFactory
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonException
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonMergePatch
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonNumber
[WARNING]   - javax.json.JsonObject
[WARNING]   - 24 more...
[WARNING] jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar, wildfly-elytron-1.10.8.Final-redhat-00001.jar define 37 overlapping classes and resources:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.AbstractLoggerProvider
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.AbstractLoggerProvider$Entry
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.AbstractMdcLoggerProvider
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerLogger
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerProvider
[WARNING]   - org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerProvider$1
[WARNING]   - 27 more...
[WARNING] aether-impl-1.7.jar, maven-aether-provider-3.0.jar, maven-core-3.0.jar, maven-model-builder-3.0.jar, maven-settings-builder-3.0.jar, plexus-cipher-1.4.jar, pl
exus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.jar, plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.4.jar, plexus-java-0.9.10.jar, plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar, sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar define 1 overlappi
ng resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/plexus/components.xml
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
[INFO] Attaching shaded artifact.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.149 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-14T20:14:36+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Instead of creating an uber jar why not copy all your dependencies with your application and set the classpath appropriately? That may help you identify whether or not the uber jar is the problem.

Comment: @ahrooran I have exactly the same issue, was you able to find a solution.

Comment: @WaleedAsif I'm really sorry for not responding to your question immediately. I hope you got the code as same as mentioned in the other question I posted in SO (link in above description). The culprit was maven / intellij cache system. So I deleted the `.m2` folder (`C:\Users\user\.m2\`) entirely and re-ran mvn clean package. This will re-install every package. Then it would work. Also make sure to update maven to latest version, because I did that too. Not sure updating solved the problem or not. So try both and tell me if you are successful. Again sorry for not responding in time